# In Microsoft.Graph AcquireTokenInteractive is called multiple times on each request

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am seeing a strange behaviour and unable to understand how do i resolve.  I see that AcquireTokenInteractive is activated/called on each request of graphClient.Me.

First on await graphClient.Me.GetAsync(); (Which is expected)
and secondly on  await graphClient.Me.Calendars.GetAsync();  (which is unexpected behaviour)
Below is my complete code sample.

**I am using Microsoft Graph .NET SDK v5**

```
  public class TokenProvider : IAccessTokenProvider
  {
      public AllowedHostsValidator AllowedHostsValidator => throw new NotImplementedException();

      public IPublicClientApplication publicClientApp;
     
      public async Task<string> GetAuthorizationTokenAsync(Uri uri, Dictionary<string, object> additionalAuthenticationContext = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
      {
          var scopes = new[] { "Calendars.Read", "User.Read" };
          AuthenticationResult authResult;
          publicClientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create("0c-a5-42-a-92")
              .WithRedirectUri("http://localhost")
              .Build();   //Client-id
          try
          {

              var accounts = await publicClientApp.GetAccountsAsync();
              authResult = await publicClientApp.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault()).ExecuteAsync();
              return authResult.AccessToken;
          }
          catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
          {
              authResult = await publicClientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
              return authResult.AccessToken;
          }

          
      }

     public async Task SignOut()
       {
          var accounts = await publicClientApp.GetAccountsAsync();
          foreach (var account in accounts)
          {
              await publicClientApp.RemoveAsync(account);
           }
         }
      }
```

In a windows1.cs

```
 TokenProvider tp;
  BaseBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
  GraphServiceClient graphClient;

    public async Task<bool> Button1_Click()
    {
        tp = new TokenProvider();
        authenticationProvider = new BaseBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider(tp);
        Microsoft.Graph.Models.User user = null;

        graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);

        user = await graphClient.Me.GetAsync();   // login screen is Called here First Time,  expected.
     }

  public async Task<List<string>> Button2_Click()
  {
      var calendars = await graphClient.Me.Calendars.GetAsync();  // login screen is called here second time, why ?
  }
```

Comment: Hit:  Every call to graphClient  triggers GetAuthorizationTokenAsync() internally.  
and during debugging it came to my knowledge that  var accounts = await publicClientApp.GetAccountsAsync(); never returns any rows, even if user had login successfully.     Where I am wrong in coding?